# Codeigniter JpGraph Installation as Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, jpgraph

I've been attempting to include the JpGraph library using CI's library function. Codeigniter will not load the jpgraph.php file because it doesn't contain a class called Jpgraph. Is there a way around this, so that I can use the native CI library instead of some sort of manual include?

Also, any other open-source or free for public sector php graphing utilities? Looking for something that will allow basic line and bar graphs.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never solved this issue. We switched to Chart.js.